# .not() function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have two buttons on my form. A user clicks on any one of the buttons and the drop down is shown, for the corresponding button. Now the user clicks randomly anywhere on the form. So now I want the dropdown to be hidden.

My code has:

```
$('html').not( "button.btn.dark.dropdown.copy" ).on 'click', (e) ->
    if $('ul.drop-menu.copy-menu').css('display') != 'none'
      $('ul.drop-menu.copy-menu').hide() 

$('html').not( "button.btn.dark.dropdown.move" ).on 'click', (e) ->
    if $('ul.drop-menu.move-menu').css('display') != 'none'
      $('ul.drop-menu.move-menu').hide()
```

In the above code, it works fine for the move button but does not work for the copy button. I am unable to find the reason for the same. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: check target existance with `e.target`!

Comment: You're selecting all `html` elements which are not `button.btn.dark.dropdown.move` elements, which is to say, you're still selecting the `html` root. You need a check within the callback to detect whether the event target was within the matched selector.

Comment: because of javascript line by line hierarchy, only last one would work. you should use target as said above, and make selection on document not on html.

Comment: Note that you can use `.toggle()` for this.

Comment: Check this jsfiddle in which I have used `e.target`. http://jsfiddle.net/RfH4g/3/

Answer (score 2):

Check closest target with in the selector,

Suppose your popup showing content is inside `.popup` class then use it's class name for checking the target

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.popup').length) { // exists only when you click on popup area otherwise will return false and will hide popup
        $('ul.drop-menu.move-menu').hide()
    }
})
```